# LoopBack4 execute a custom group by with find or use existing methods

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback, loopback4

Hi is use loopback 4 for customs rest

this is my collection when i use console.log of this find `const resultfilters = await this.reactionsRepository.find(filter)`

```
[ Reactions {
  id: 'c3RyaW5nOnN0cmluZw==',
  websiteId: 'string',
  sectionSlug: 'string',
  contentId: 'string',
  reactionId: 'string',
  bearerToken: undefined },


   Reactions {
    id: 'string',
    websiteId: 'string',
    sectionSlug: 'string',
    contentId: 'string',
    reactionId: 'string',
    bearerToken: undefined },
  Reactions {
    id: 'string1',
    websiteId: 'string',
    sectionSlug: 'string',
    contentId: 'string',
    reactionId: 'string',
    bearerToken: undefined } ]
```

i want to use group by in custom select for example

```
const resultfilters = await this.reactionsRepository.find(filter)
```

and this filter use a custom group by and count, this step i dont know how make but something like that

```
const resultgroup = await this.reactionsRepository.groupby(resultfilters)
const resultend = await this.reactionsRepository.count(resultgroup)
```

if i can use, how make this with loopback 4?

or in some case i need use the before filter and later apply the filter with my custom group by and count

```
const resultfilters = await this.reactionsRepository.find(filter)
const reactions = (this.reactionsRepository.dataSource.connector as any).collection("Reactions");
  var collection = await reacciones.aggregate(
    [
      {"$group" : 
        {_id:{websiteId:'$' +,status:"$status"}, count:{$sum:1}}
      }, 
      {$sort:{"_id.source":1}}
    ]
  )
```

Comment: Please provide example documents in your mongodb collection

Comment: hi i add my examples collections

Comment: the example documents you provided in your update is not valid JSON.  You can validate your JSON using online tools such as https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/